# combining two arrays , one from array[] another is from array2 = array(); php

Tags: php, mysql

im not sure how can i combine these two arrays together:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $rows[] = $r;
}

  $out = array("$r,'fruit'=> 'orange','location'=> 'home , 'test'=> 'off'");
```

As you can see i put all the mysql table data into an array called **$rows[]**
and i have another array called **$out**

how can i combine this two so i can json encode them with this:

```
$result_string = json_encode($combined);
print $callback.'('.result_string.');';
```

Comment: have you gone through `array_merge` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_merge`

```
 $result = array_merge($rows, $out);
```

**[See PHP Manual: array_Merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)**

Comment: oh theres an merge function for array , thanks for pointing out!